# How do I know which RFC are in use?

Tags: standards, rfc

The RFC index ( https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/index ) suggests that HTTP Version 2 (RFC7540) and HTTP 1.1 (RFC2068) both have a standard of PROPOSED STANDARD but are pretty well industry standard for HTTP. Does the IETF explicitly or implicitly track RFCs which have been widely accepted, or have a formalized acceptance process?